# Function that returns another function '->' symbol

Tags: python, function

What is the `->` symbol for returning a function from another function?

```
def OneFunc(x) -> def:
    return AnotherFunc
```

Does not seem to work, nor `function` / `func` ..

Answer (score 3):

You want the `Callable` generic type.

```
from typing import Callable

def OneFunc(x: int) -> Callable[[], None]:
    return lambda: AnotherFunc('5', x)
```

The parameters to `Callable` depend on the signature of the function you're returning.

Comment: Is there a way without importing?

Comment: Could you explain your use case further?  Is this for a school assignment where you need to type something using only built-in types?

Comment: No school stuff or work that I need to hand-in. I was just curious about this :-)

Comment: Is there a way without imports? Yes. Is it better than what this answer proposed? Absolutely not. (If you instantiate a function and query its type, then you have the type of a function... but that's a lot of extra work, unidiomatic and unclear to readers).

Comment: Having type declarations for anything beyond the most simple cases is generally going to require the `typing` module.  You see people sometimes using declarations like `list` or `dict` (the builtin types) instead of `typing.List` and `typing.Dict`, but the builtin types don't support generics so they're almost worthless as type declarations.  E.g. if you declare a `dict` it's basically the same as `Dict[Any, Any]`, which isn't much better than no declaration at all.

Comment: You could do something very artificial looking, like `def OneFunc(x: int) -> type(lambda: ())`, but there's no reason *not* to import a module from the standard library.